# Automate shadowsocks proxy server setup

Tags: automation, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am going to a highly Internet censorship country which blocked Youtube or Gmail or twitter. So I decide to setup a shadowsocks proxy server, on a Raspberry PI and give it to my friend who live in a low censorship area. I use her internet to visit my Gmail. Unfortunately my friend is totally computer illiterate, and she often move house. That means I need to automatic every network config of the pi.

That means the Raspi should automatically recognize new network and initialize the server. So here is my plan:

1. Every time power up the Raspi, auto recognize IP and auto send to my safe email.
2. The Raspi is probably under a local area network. NaT(Network Address Translation) or frp ( fast reverse proxy) should expose Raspi to public internet. Then I can find my Raspi.
3. Setup shadowshocks server on my Raspi, and it can change the server configuration automatically.

Then Raspi would automate deploy to the new network. I only visit my safe email and change my shadowsocks client config.

**1. Is this a feasible plan?**
**2. I fininshed step 1, and blocked at step 2. I need help to solve step 2,3. Please give me some course or plan**
Thank you for your time and any comment will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I see in your plan is in step 2:

Normally it requires setting up NAT on the wifi router to make the Shadowsocks user port open to the WLAN side. And this could be difficult to be automated on the raspberry pi, especially the wifi routers may be unpredictable various.

About step 3, it shouldn't be a problem, the service should listen on a private IP address which has nothing to do with your client setting, and the port could be fixed, all you want to do is to supervise your service to make sure it stays strong.

I would recommend setting up VPN services in a cloud environment if the costs are not a big problem. AWS has a one-year free tier plan that may be useful. Take a look at this project, [aws-cfn-vpn](https://github.com/alexzhangs/aws-cfn-vpn), it should provide you a solution and keep your hands clean as much as possible.

Comment: Dear alex,  I totally agree wity you. I blocked in Step 2 for a long time and realize auto-config the wifi router beyond my skill. Maybe AWS is a practical way.